# Can't hide numpad in iPhone Xcode4.3

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

This is my code below.  I can call my numpad but I can't hide it.  How to hide it?

```
- (IBAction)loopBtn:(id)sender {
    loopBtn.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [loopBtn becomeFirstResponder];
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide keyboard by making your `UIView` an `UIControl` (`UIControl` is subclass of `UIView`). Then Write an `IBAction` method that is executed when you touch that `UIControl`(formerly `UIView`). Open interface editor and select main `UIView`. Then open identity inspector and change it class to `UIControl` from `UIView`. Now in your viewcontroller write an IBAction method.

```
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Now connect your UIView's TouchUpInside event to this IBAction method. This will hide keyboard whenever you touch outside of your textfield.